# how to show the position of object in a list

Tags: c#, list, collections

i have a list full of objects, and i want to show where each object "sit\position ":
like:
 objecta-name-0
 objectb-name-1
 objectc-name-2
 objectc-name-3
 objectc-name-4 --- and so on...

whats the best way of doing this ?
thanks :)

```
public List <Custome> custome = new List <Custome>();

   public override void Display(Custome c)
    {
     /////
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you give us sufficient information about your issue?

Comment: Do you want to see `Custome` position in list?

Answer (score 3):

```
public override int Display(Custome c)
{
    return custome.IndexOf(c);
}
```

Comment: Returns `int` in method with `void` return type!

Comment: Remove `return` and that will be +1 :)

Comment: @HamletHakobyan my mistake. Consequence of copypasting from the question.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: Removing `return` would make that method pretty useless ;-) Changing the return type to `int` makes more sense. And that's what he already did.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth method `Display()` should not return anything :)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: You mean because of the name? That's debatable, it depends on where that method actually sits.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth possibly name `XXX` also good in some context. But original intent of this method is displaying customer (that's why it is void method in question)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I completely understand, but you could use the overload of [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) that takes an indexed expression:

```
var newList = custome.Select((c, i)=>new {Custome=c, Index = i});
foreach(var item in newList)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}",item.Custome.Name, item.Index);
}
```

Or if you just want to find the position of one item use

```
public override void Display(Custome c)
{
    int index = custome.IndexOf(c);
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}",c.Name, index);
}
```